# Programming language essential to Security careers

Tags: security

Having absolutely no coding/programming experience my professor told me to take at least one programming course. What programming language is it imperative I learn  if I aspire to enter into the cyber security field?

Comment: You will find that this question is off-topic on pretty much every SE site. As for [su], see [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: What did your professor recommend? Why not ask him?

Comment: noted I will refrain from open ended questions like this.

Comment: Your question is a bit like asking which is the one food you need to know to prepare to be a good chef. Cyber security supposes (amongst many other topics) that you understand the logic of many programming languages, Which you can't without mastering at least a few of them. As David already suggested, ask your professor, which one you should start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any programming language should suffice. It's not so much the language that is important starting out, but rather learning the basic concepts of coding and scripting. That is, there are universal concepts about coding that are more important to learn initially. Those concepts will then lead you to ask the right questions to ask yourself when you're writing or reviewing code in a different language.

I would recommend knowing a bit of bash and SQL, which are scripting languages. These will help you to better understand the execution of cybersecurity concepts such as SEIM, MITRE chain, vulnerabilities and remediation, and reporting.

Relative to cyber security, I'm not certain that learning any specific programming language or not would hold a particular benefit without knowing what type of role on what team you would fulfill.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to make future questions more suitable to the forum.